# Emerge (Gentoo) reports package as being installed and not installed

Tags: linux, gentoo, emerge

I am trying to upgrade a Gentoo installation from end 2018 to the current version (March 2020). I am following the instructions given [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Upgrading_Gentoo#Updating_old_systems).

I have a host installation which contains an up-to-date (March 2020) Gentoo system, and from there I have mounted the old installation under `<old-inst>`. I am trying to upgrade using the command:

```
emerge --ask --verbose --verbose-conflicts --update --deep --newuse --root=<old-inst> --config-root=<old-inst> @world --backtrack=20000
```

This has produced several conflicts between already installed packages and packages that would be installed by the update. I resolved these by removing the old package and trying to update again with the command above. My plan is to install the removed packages again after the update has run successfully.

This strategy has worked for many conflicts but now I have reached a conflict I cannot resolve. Here is the information from `emerge --update ...`:

```
!!! Multiple package instances within a single package slot have been pulled
!!! into the dependency graph, resulting in a slot conflict:

dev-python/cffi:0

    (dev-python/cffi-1.11.4:0/1.11.4::gentoo, installed) USE="-doc -test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_6" pulled in by
        >=dev-python/cffi-1.8:0/1.11.4=[python_targets_python2_7(-),-python_single_target_python2_7(-),python_targets_python3_6(-),-python_single_target_python3_6(-),-python_single_target_python3_7(-),-python_single_target_python3_8(-)] required by (dev-python/cryptography-2.8-r1:0/0::gentoo, installed) USE="-idna -libressl -test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_6 (-pypy3) (-python3_7) (-python3_8)"
                     ^^^^^^^^^^
    >=dev-python/cffi-1.1:0/1.11.4=[python_targets_python2_7(-),-python_single_target_python2_7(-),python_targets_python3_6(-),-python_single_target_python3_6(-),-python_single_target_python3_7(-)] required by (dev-python/bcrypt-3.1.6:0/0::gentoo, installed) USE="-test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_6 (-python3_7)"
                     ^^^^^^^^^^
    dev-python/cffi:0/1.11.4=[python_targets_python3_6(-),-python_single_target_python3_6(-),-python_single_target_python3_7(-)] required by (dev-python/pyzmq-16.0.2:0/0::gentoo, installed) USE="(-doc) -test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_6 (-python3_7)"
               ^^^^^^^^^^

    (dev-python/cffi-1.13.2:0/1.13.2::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) USE="-doc -test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_6 (-python3_7) (-python3_8)" pulled in by >=dev-python/cffi-1.1:0/1.13.2=[python_targets_python2_7(-),-python_single_target_python2_7(-),python_targets_python3_6(-),-python_single_target_python3_6(-),-python_single_target_python3_7(-)] required by (dev-python/bcrypt-3.1.6:0/0::gentoo, installed in '/systemrescuecd/customcd/files/') USE="-test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_6 (-python3_7)"
                     ^^^^^^^^^^
        dev-python/cffi:0/1.13.2=[python_targets_python2_7(-),python_targets_python3_6(-),-python_single_target_python2_7(-),-python_single_target_python3_6(-),-python_single_target_python3_7(-)] required by (dev-python/pyzmq-16.0.2:0/0::gentoo, installed in '/systemrescuecd/customcd/files/') USE="(-doc) -test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_6 (-python3_7)"
```

If I interpret this information correctly, at least two different versions of package `dev-python/cffi` would be installed: e.g. version `1.13.2` is pulled by package `dev-python/bcrypt`, and version `1.11.4` is already installed. So my plan was to remove package `dev-python/cffi` first and then try `emerge --update ...` again. So I did

```
emerge --ask --root=<old-inst> --config-root=<old-inst> -C dev-python/cffi
```

but emerge reports that the package is not installed, which puzzles me. If I then try `emerge --update ...` I get again the information that one version of the package is already installed. So, is the package installed or is it not? And how to resolve this conflict? Or in case the package information is corrupt, is there a way to repair it?

Comment: Are you sure you have a recent snapshot? On my box, I don't have the ebuild for cffi-1.11.4 anymore, e.g. `eix dev-python/cffi --format '<availableversions:EQNAMEVERSION>'` prints only 1.13.2 and 1.14.0. Could you run `emerge --sync` successfully? What is the contents of `/usr/portage/dev-python/cffi`?